# Is there a way to chain snakemake rules without touch files?

Tags: chaining, snakemake

Is there a way to accomplish the following helpAll rule without creating the unwanted empty files helpA, helpB, helpC, then deleting them?

```
rule helpA:
    output: touch("helpA")
    shell: "echo 'help on subject <A>'"

rule helpB:
    output: touch("helpB")
    shell: "echo 'help on subject <B>'"

rule helpC:
    output: touch("helpC")
    shell: "echo 'help on subject <C>'"

rule helpAll:
    input: "helpA","helpB","helpC"
    shell: "rm {input}
```

A nice solution would be a rule dependency of the following sort, but this is not valid snakecode:

```
rule helpAll:
    input: rules.helpA,rules.helpB,rules.helpC
```

or:

```
rule helpAll:
    depends_on_rule: helpA,helpB,helpC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that snakemake would work properly without creating files on disk.

But you could use **temp** so that the files are automatically deleted. More in detail, from the documentation:

> Snakemake allows to mark output files as temporary, such that they are
>   deleted once every consuming job has been executed.

[reference](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/advanced.html#tutorial-temp-and-protected-files)

Comment: You can even combine them: `temp(touch("file"))`.